# How to ignore GMT-offset in the date string

Tags: momentjs, moment-timezone, dayjs

The date I'm receiving is `2022-04-01T19:49:58-0600` and I need to show that 19:49 without calculating the GMT (-0600)

I tried this in moment.js and it worked:

```
moment('2022-04-01T19:49:58-0600').utcOffset('2022-04-01T19:49:58-0600').format('h:mm a')
```

as I get `'7:49 pm'` which is correct.

Now my problem is I cannot find the same thing on Dayjs.js!

If I use `dayjs('2022-04-01T19:49:58-0600').utcOffset('2022-04-01T19:49:58-0600').format('h:mm a')` I get this error: `'Invalid Date'`

Answer (score 0):

```
  function timeInMiliSeconds = () => {
  var date = new Date();
  var hour = date.getUTCHours();
  var min = date.getUTCMinutes(); 
  var sec = date.getUTCSeconds();
  var formatedHour = hour > 9 ? hour : "0" + hour
  var formatedMinute = min > 9 ? min : "0" + min
  var formatedSecond = sec > 9 ? sec : "0" + sec
  var timeStamps 
  if (hour > 0){
    timeStamps = hour >1 ? formatedHour + ":" + formatedMinute + ":" + formatedSecond + " hours" :  formatedHour + ":" + formatedMinute + ":" + formatedSecond + " hour"
  } else if (min > 0){
    timeStamps = min > 1 ? formatedMinute + ":" + formatedSecond + " minutes" :  formatedMinute + ":" + formatedSecond + " minute"
  }else{
    timeStamps =  sec > 1 ? formatedSecond + " seconds" :  formatedSecond + " second"  
  }
  return timeStamps
}
```

Comment: Try to format the code example better.